# How to use npm-shrinkwrap with workspaces?

Tags: node.js, security, npm, npm-shrinkwrap

I have a monorepo project, with one of the packages being a cli. And to prevent npm supply chain attack I am thinking of using `npm-shrinkwrap`.

The documentation [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npm-shrinkwrap-json) says:

> The recommended use-case for npm-shrinkwrap.json is applications deployed through the publishing process on the registry: for example, daemons and command-line tools intended as global installs or devDependencies

This is exactly what i want as I am deploying a command-line tools. The only problem is, it seems npm-shrinkwrap does not support workspaces.

Let's say the cli part of my monorepo can be found in the path: `/code/packages/cli`, when I switch to it and run `npm shrinkwrap` I get the error:

```
npm ERR! code ENOWORKSPACES
npm ERR! This command does not support workspaces.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/me/.npm/_logs/2022-05-16T20_53_41_147Z-debug-0.log
```

If I switch to the root of the project, that is `/code/` and I run `npm shrinkwrap`, it does generates a `npm-shrinkwrap.json` with the following structure:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "lockfileVersion": 2,
  "requires": true,
  "packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "root",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "workspaces": [
        "packages/*"
      ],
      "devDependencies": {
        "lerna": "^4.0.0"
      }
    },
    "packages/cli": {
      "name": "@proj/cli",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "extraneous": true,
      "license": "ISC"
    }
  }
}
```

But the only problem is, this is not the exact structure that should be created for the `cli`. Also when I publish the package (using lerna), the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` is never included in the `cli` package.

Any tips on how to make npm-shrinkwrap work with workspaces?

Basically how to have the `npm-shrinkwrap.json` generated for a package in a monorepo and have that inlcuded when that package is released?

Answer (score -1):

The tool [`npm-lockfile`](https://npm.im/npm-lockfile) uses npm's internals and works inside of monorepos.

Unfortunately, they're using an old version of `@npm/arborist`, so it doesn't quite work properly, and you can use [my patch](https://github.com/forivall/npm-lockfile) for now